# Why do I get null if I create an Instance of my Room database?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

I'm making a reminder app. When the phone is rebooted or cold booted I need to refresh the reminders via the Alarm Manager. For that I use a seperate Broadcast Receiver which receives the ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED action. In it I want to access the database to refresh the reminders stored in it. The way I'm currently doing it I only get null objects.

This is my Database:

```
@Database(entities = [Reminder::class], version = 11)
abstract class ReminderDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
abstract val reminderDao: ReminderDao

companion object {
    @Volatile
    private var INSTANCE: ReminderDatabase? = null

    fun createInstance(context: Context): ReminderDatabase {
        synchronized(this) {
            var instance = INSTANCE
            if (instance == null) {
                println("db instance created")
                instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    ReminderDatabase::class.java,
                    "Reminder Database"
                ).fallbackToDestructiveMigration().build()
            }
            INSTANCE = instance
            return instance
        }
    }
}
}
```

I'm trying to access the database inside my Receiver using

```
val dbInstance = ReminderDatabase.createInstance(context!!)
val reminderDao = dbInstance.reminderDao
val reminders = reminderDao.getAllReminders().value
```

Doing it like this **reminders** always turns out to be null, not just when doing it on boot via the receiver, also when testing it while the app is running e.g. via a button.

This is the **getAllReminders()** query from my DAO:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Reminder ORDER BY timeInMillis ASC")
fun getAllReminders(): LiveData<List<Reminder>>
```

I usually access this via the ViewModel but otherwise in the same manner. The value of the Live Data I receive there is as expected and exactly what I would need here too. How can I achieve this?

Any help would be seriously greatly appreciated, this is literally the last step before the app is done. I'm open to questions and can provide more code as needed!

Comment: You can't access access Room Database when the app is not running. But you can use Workers to update the refresh the reminders.

Comment: Show the code for Reminder entity

Comment: `LiveData` only has a `value` if you `observe` it. Where are you observing your `LiveData`?

Comment: @ianhanniballake I am observing it in my HomeFragment to display the data in a RecyclerView

Comment: @mightyWOZ it's too long for a comment. I also doubt it'd help.

Comment: @VaibhavGoyal thank you! could you elaborate a bit? I'll try it eitherway.

Comment: @user12287130 you can refer to this link, https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager to learn how to use Work Manager in Android. Basically what you can do is to schedule a Work using Work Manager when you receive the broadcast to refresh the room database. Just do the work what you are doing in onReceive() method in Worker Thread.